# How can I get all the strings that have the same pattern

Tags: java, string, regression

I have an xml file that has this structure

```
<expression>[Customer ].[Sales ].[L_MOIS]</expression><expression>cast_varchar([Customer ].[Sales ].[L_MOIS_ANNEE])
+ ' ' + 
cast_varchar([Customer ].[Sales ].[C_ANNEE])</expression></dataItem></selection><detailFilters><detailFilter><filterExpression>[Customer ].[Sales ].[DT_JOUR] <= getdate()</filterExpression></detailFilter></detailFilters></query><query name="RSmag"><source><model /></source><selection><dataItem aggregate="none" name="Code magasin"><expression>[Customer statistics].[Stores].[C_MAGASIN]</expression></dataItem><dataItem aggregate="none" name="Libellé magasin" sort="ascending"><expression>[Customer statistics].[Stores].[L_MAGASIN]</expression></dataItem></selection><detailFilters><detailFilter><filterExpression>[Customer statistics].[Stores].[C_DEPOT] <>'500'</filterExpression></detailFilter><detailFilter><filterExpression>[Customer statistics].[Stores].[C_MAGASIN] not in ('005120';'005130';'005140')</filterExpression></detailFilter></detailFilters>
</query><query name="CAdept_avec_metier_cumul"><source><model /></source><selection><dataItem aggregate="none" name="Cod Metier" rollupAggregate="none"><expression>[Customer ].[Articles].[COD_DPTG]</expression></dataItem><dataItem name="Nombre de tickets" rollupAggregate="total">
<expression>count(distinct [Customer ].[Sales ].[ID_TICKET])</expression></dataItem><dataItem name="Nombre de tickets non affecté" rollupAggregate="total"><expression>count(distinct 
(case 
when [Customer ].[Sales ].[C_AFFECTATION] <> 1  
then [Customer ].[Sales ].[ID_TICKET]
else null 
end)
)</expression>
```

I want to extract all the names of tab, in result I should have:
[Customer ].[Sales ].[C_ANNEE]
[Customer ].[Sales ].[DT_JOUR]

But now what I'm getting is:

Customer

Sales

C_ANNEE

```
File f = new File("");  
        BufferedReader in = new BufferedReader(
                new InputStreamReader(new FileInputStream(f), "UTF-8"));
        String str;
        while ((str = in.readLine()) != null) {

            Matcher m = Pattern.compile("\\[(.*?)\\]").matcher(str);
            while (m.find()) {
                listres.add(m.group(1));

            }
        }
```

Comment: Don't use regex for xml documents, use an xml parser like XPath

Comment: Show an example input file

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Break the problem into two separate parts:

1) Parse the XML data using a suitable XML parser, to extract the text we want.

2) For the extracted text fields, use a regular expression to extract the required sub-strings.

The following example uses a SAX parser (I am using Java 13, by the way).

Assume we have a file containing the following XML:

```
<root>
<query name="RSmag">
  <source>
    <model />
  </source>
  <selection>
    <dataItem aggregate="none" name="Code magasin">
      <expression>
        [Customer ].[Sales ].[L_MOIS]
      </expression>
      <expression>
        cast_varchar([Customer ].[Sales ].[L_MOIS_ANNEE]) + ' ' + cast_varchar([Customer ].[Sales ].[C_ANNEE])
      </expression>
    </dataItem>
  </selection>
  <detailFilters>
    <detailFilter>
      <filterExpression>
        [Customer ].[Sales ].[DT_JOUR] &lt;= getdate()
      </filterExpression>
    </detailFilter>
  </detailFilters>
</query>
<query name="RSmag">
  <source>
    <model />
  </source>
  <selection>
    <dataItem aggregate="none" name="Code magasin">
      <expression>
        [Customer statistics].[Stores].[C_MAGASIN]
      </expression>
    </dataItem>
    <dataItem aggregate="none" name="Libellé magasin" sort="ascending">
      <expression>
        [Customer statistics].[Stores].[L_MAGASIN]
      </expression>
    </dataItem>
  </selection>
  <detailFilters>
    <detailFilter>
      <filterExpression>
        [Customer statistics].[Stores].[C_DEPOT] &lt;&gt; '500'
      </filterExpression>
    </detailFilter>
    <detailFilter>
      <filterExpression>
        [Customer statistics].[Stores].[C_MAGASIN] 
        not in ('005120';'005130';'005140')
      </filterExpression>
    </detailFilter>
  </detailFilters>
</query>
<query name="CAdept_avec_metier_cumul">
  <source>
    <model />
  </source>
  <selection>
    <dataItem aggregate="none" name="Cod Metier" rollupAggregate="none">
      <expression>
        [Customer ].[Articles].[COD_DPTG]
      </expression>
    </dataItem>
    <dataItem name="Nombre de tickets" rollupAggregate="total">
      <expression>
        count(distinct [Customer ].[Sales ].[ID_TICKET])
      </expression>
    </dataItem>
    <dataItem name="Nombre de tickets non affecté" rollupAggregate="total">
      <expression>count(distinct 
                  (case 
                   when [Customer ].[Sales ].[C_AFFECTATION] &lt;&gt; 1  
                   then [Customer ].[Sales ].[ID_TICKET]
                   else null 
                   end)
                  )
      </expression>
    </dataItem>
  </selection>
</query>
</root>
```

Note the following:

a) I made an educated guess to create a valid XML document, based on the question's sample data.

b) I escaped the `<` and `>` symbols in the text, by using `&lt;` and `&gt;`.

### Step 1 - Parsing the Data

This solution [uses SAX](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/jaxp/sax/parsing.html) for parsing - there are plenty of alternatives.

The following will read each line of the input file, discarding any tags which are not `<expression>` or `<filterExpression>` tags. This set can be adjusted as needed (`watchedElements`).

The code collects the text inside each of these tags, and cleans it up by removing newlines, and extra whitespace.

This gives us a set of 10 text strings, like this:

```
[Customer ].[Sales ].[L_MOIS]
cast_varchar([Customer ].[Sales ].[L_MOIS_ANNEE]) + ' ' + cast_varchar([Customer ].[Sales ].[C_ANNEE])
[Customer ].[Sales ].[DT_JOUR] <= getdate()
[Customer statistics].[Stores].[C_MAGASIN]
[Customer statistics].[Stores].[L_MAGASIN]
[Customer statistics].[Stores].[C_DEPOT] <> '500'
[Customer statistics].[Stores].[C_MAGASIN] not in ('005120';'005130';'005140')
[Customer ].[Articles].[COD_DPTG]
count(distinct [Customer ].[Sales ].[ID_TICKET])
count(distinct (case when [Customer ].[Sales ].[C_AFFECTATION] <> 1 then [Customer ].[Sales ].[ID_TICKET] else null end) )
```

### Step 2 - Applying the Regex

For each of these strings we use a regular expression to find the data we want:

```
\[.*?\](\.\[.*?\])*
```

This searches for an opening "[", through to the next "]", and it repeats this for zero or more subsequent "[" and "]" strings separated by a period.

To deal with unwanted sub-matches we only keep group zero:

```
Matcher m = pattern.matcher(text);
while (m.find()) {
    System.out.println("*** Matches found  : " + m.group(0));
}
```

This gives us the following 12 results:

```
[Customer ].[Sales ].[L_MOIS]
[Customer ].[Sales ].[L_MOIS_ANNEE]
[Customer ].[Sales ].[C_ANNEE]
[Customer ].[Sales ].[DT_JOUR]
[Customer statistics].[Stores].[C_MAGASIN]
[Customer statistics].[Stores].[L_MAGASIN]
[Customer statistics].[Stores].[C_DEPOT]
[Customer statistics].[Stores].[C_MAGASIN]
[Customer ].[Articles].[COD_DPTG]
[Customer ].[Sales ].[ID_TICKET]
[Customer ].[Sales ].[C_AFFECTATION]
[Customer ].[Sales ].[ID_TICKET]
```

### Full Solution

```
import javax.xml.parsers.SAXParser;
import javax.xml.parsers.SAXParserFactory;
import org.xml.sax.Attributes;
import org.xml.sax.SAXException;
import org.xml.sax.helpers.DefaultHandler;
import java.util.Set;
import java.util.HashSet;
import java.util.regex.Pattern;
import java.util.regex.Matcher;

public class ParseFromFileUsingSax {

    // Looks for an opening "[" followed by a closing "]" with an 
    // optional "." to string items together into one group.
    Pattern pattern = Pattern.compile("\\[.*?\\](\\.\\[.*?\\])*");

    public void parseUsingSax() {
        try {

            SAXParserFactory factory = SAXParserFactory.newInstance();
            SAXParser saxParser = factory.newSAXParser();

            // the tags we will inspect (all others will be skipped):
            Set<String> watchedElements = new HashSet();
            watchedElements.add("expression");
            watchedElements.add("filterExpression");

            DefaultHandler handler = new DefaultHandler() {

                private boolean inElement = false;
                private StringBuilder stringBuilder;

                @Override
                public void startElement(String uri, String localName, String name,
                        Attributes attributes) throws SAXException {
                    if (watchedElements.contains(name)) {
                        inElement = true;
                        stringBuilder = new StringBuilder();
                    }
                }

                @Override
                public void characters(char[] buffer, int start, int length) throws SAXException {
                    if (inElement) {
                        stringBuilder.append(buffer, start, length);
                    }
                }

                @Override
                public void endElement(String uri, String localName,
                        String name) throws SAXException {
                    if (watchedElements.contains(name)) {
                        inElement = false;
                        String extractedText = formatString(stringBuilder.toString());
                        System.out.println();
                        System.out.println("Extracted XML text : " + extractedText);
                        printMatches(extractedText);
                    }
                }

            };

            saxParser.parse("C:/tmp/query_data.xml", handler);

        } catch (Exception e) {
            System.err.print(e);
        }

    }

    private String formatString(String text) {
        text = text.replaceAll("\\r\\n|\\r|\\n", " "); // remove newlines
        text = text.replaceAll("  *", " "); // collapse multiple spaces
        return text.trim(); // remove leading/trailing whitespace
    }

    private void printMatches(String text) {
        Matcher m = pattern.matcher(text);
        while (m.find()) {
            System.out.println("*** Matches found  : " + m.group(0));
        }
    }

}
```